# What is meant by "game mechanics"?

Tags: terminology, mechanics

What are **game mechanics**?

Conceptually I think of the mechanics of the game as *how it's played* but the definition is a little fuzzy.  I don't think rules and mechanics are the same - although I think they're related.  Help me sort this out in my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fantastic article on this topic by Miguel Sicart called *[Defining Game Mechanics](http://gamestudies.org/0802/articles/sicart)*, it is mostly related to Video Games, but the the same definitions can broadly be applied to Board Games as well.

Essentially **Game Mechanics** are actions that modify the game state, and it is this modification of the game state that results in *gameplay*.
While Game Mechanics can, and should, be defined by rules, they are not themselves rules.

In a more colloquial form, if you're changing anything in the game, whether physical or conceptual, you are implementing a Game Mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

Game mechanics are the the building blocks of a game.  The basic actions players can make in a game.  For example, a game can implement randomness in several ways: rolling a dice, card drafting, a spinning top, etc.

Some known mechanics:

- Worker Placement
- Area Majority
- Auction (many different kinds)
- Cooperative Game

See [BGG-Game-mechanics](https://boardgamegeek.com/browse/boardgamemechanic), for the full list of game mechanics in board games.

Further reading: [What are Game Mechanics](https://www.bunchball.com/gamification/game-mechanics)